# Python Unit Test : How do I test loading data from database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using `psycopg2-binary` to connect to a database. This is the class I've written to query data from the database given a query and return as a dataframe. I'm stuck on how I would unit test this function without having to hit the real database.

code :

```py
import pandas as pd

class HitDB(object):
    def __init__(self, db_con):
        self.conn = db_con
        

    def load_data(self, query):
        df = pd.read_sql(
            sql = query, 
            con = self.conn
        )
        return df
```

Comment: You could run a database in a container, (e.g. with Docker) and point your tests at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the function does is pass its query and `self.conn` to another function, mock `pd.read_sql` and check it receives the expected arguments.

Which suggests getting rid of this function and just call `pd.read_sql` directly.

---

If it did something more significant with the database, run a local PostgreSQL server (locally or with something like Docker), load the schema, and [use factories](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to populate it with test data as needed.